# How to find the intersection of two pandas dataframe (calculate sample counts) and speed up the process?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two matrices: one is individual X SNPs, and one is individual X phenotypes. I want to create a matrix such that the format is SNP x Phenotypes. each cell should represent the number of common samples from the two matrices. The problem I encountered is that I used two for loop to modify the cell value, but the matrix is 529 x 1502, and it takes more than a day to finish on the server. I wonder if any other methods can speed up the process.

Thanks in advance, and below is the code I am currently using:
if SNPs = 1 then individuals have the snp and if pheno = 1 then individual has the disease.

```
snp_data = snp_data[snp_data['eid'].isin(pheno_matrix_df['eid'])]
snp_phenotype_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=snp_data.columns[1:], columns=pheno_matrix_df.columns[1:])

for snp in snp_data.columns[1:]:
    for phenotype in pheno_matrix_df.columns[1:]:
        eids_with_snp = set(snp_data[snp_data[snp] == 1]['eid'])

        eids_with_phenotype = set(filtered_matrix_df[filtered_matrix_df[phenotype] >= 1]['eid'])

        snp_phenotype_matrix.loc[snp, phenotype] = len(eids_with_snp.intersection(eids_with_phenotype))

snp_phenotype_matrix.to_csv("sample_count_matrix.csv")
```

Comment: Can you supply a sample of your data (not a picture).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: for loops and dataframes are a poor combination:  [for loops and dataframes exmplanation](https://youtu.be/0EkFJNTOs7E)